# How to make an accordion list inside another accordion list(2 levels)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im using this example to make an accordion list, but i need an accordion list with 2 levels, something like:

```
-Group
  -Child1
     Child2
     Child2
  +Child1
  +Child1
+Group
+Group
```

http://codepen.io/drr/pen/emxoaL

See the Pen Ionic Accordion List with Static Elements by Daniel R. (@drr) on CodePen.

Comment: did you find solution ? pls post. I was looking for similar implementation

Comment: Yes, ill post an example of what i did as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a solution, i used the same 2 functions to replicate the behavior of the list.

See the Pen KdMRgN by David Leyva (@morsiki) on CodePen.

```
<script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

http://codepen.io/morsiki/pen/KdMRgN?editors=101